# Add legends by color in Plotly scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly

```
trace = go.Scatter(
x=x_pca_df['Principle'],
y=x_pca_df['Second'],
mode='markers',
marker=dict(color=home_data['PriceLevel'], size=4, showscale=False))

data = [trace]

layout = dict(
title='PCA Analysis',
xaxis=dict(title='First Principle Component'),
yaxis=dict(title='Second Principle Component'))
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

I want to have legends shown by the side of this plotly chart. Therefore, people can understand what the color of the points stand for. I cannot find a proper solution anywhere.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue here is two fold, first your PriceLevel is an integer so the plot is using it as a scale, which is why you specified `showscale=False`. If you change that to `showscale=True` you will get a legend of sorts but it will be a scale and you want points.

That's the second part; if you want to show them as individual scales you will have to set them up as individual traces.

For Example

```
# Set up a trace for each level of PriceLevel
trace1 = go.Scatter(
x=x_pca_df.query(" PriceLevel==1")['Principle'],
y=x_pca_df.query(" PriceLevel==1")['Second'],
# Add a name for each trace to appear in the legend
name = 'PriceLevel 1', 
mode='markers',
marker=dict(color='rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)', size=4, showscale=False))

trace2 = go.Scatter(
x=x_pca_df.query(" PriceLevel==2")['Principle'],
y=x_pca_df.query(" PriceLevel==2")['Second'],
name = 'PriceLevel 2', 
mode='markers',
marker=dict(color='rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)', size=4, showscale=False))

# Join them all together 
data = [trace1, trace2]

layout = dict(
title='PCA Analysis',
xaxis=dict(title='First Principle Component'),
yaxis=dict(title='Second Principle Component'))
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Hopefully that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify filename parameter. Try this and let me know if it works.

```
trace = go.Scatter(
x=x_pca_df['Principle'],
y=x_pca_df['Second'],
mode='markers',
marker=dict(color=home_data['PriceLevel'], size=4, showscale=False))

data = [trace]

layout = dict(
title='PCA Analysis',
xaxis=dict(title='First Principle Component'),
yaxis=dict(title='Second Principle Component'), showlegend = True)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename = 'show-legend')
```

Comment: I did it according to your suggestion, but as you can see from my post, it shows 'trace 0' but not 'PriceLevel'

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify parameter [name](https://plot.ly/python/legend/#legend-names) in your `trace`. As I think from seeing the plot, you have four `traces`. So you need to select `name` for each `trace` and choose what you want to see for each of them.

Code:

```
trace = go.Scatter(
x=x_pca_df['Principle'],
y=x_pca_df['Second'],
#Set parameter name to what you want to see in legend
name = 'PriceLevel',
mode='markers',
marker=dict(color=home_data['PriceLevel'], size=4, showscale=False))

data = [trace]

layout = dict(
title='PCA Analysis',
xaxis=dict(title='First Principle Component'),
# Do not forget specify showlegend as True
yaxis=dict(title='Second Principle Component'), showlegend = True)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
# Parameter filename just create a html file in your python script directory with name
iplot(fig, filename = 'show-legend')
```

Comment: not working...size=4 means the point size but not 4 subplots. And I hope to have the legend shown by the color('PriceLevel'). Your suggestion can only show the legend of 'trace 0' but not by color of the points.

Comment: You set `color` to `home_data['PriceLevel']`. Can you get some data from this column, how this column looks like? (such output of `print(home_data['PriceLevel']`))

Comment: home_data['PriceLevel'] = pd.qcut(home_data.SalePrice, [0, .25, .5, .75, 1], labels=[1,2,3,4])

Comment: They are classfied by the price and I cut them into four segments.

Comment: Hmm, I can suggest to create column for each of segment (four columns). Then create four trace (each trace for each column). Name column as you want (such as "first segment" etc.) but do not forget to set parameter name in trace (such as "0.25 segment" or something similar). Choose also in first trace first column, in second trace - second etc. Then, when you set showlegend=True you should see 4 segments with names and next to names color of each segment

Comment: @ZakkYang, if my comment helped you?

Comment: Hi Oysiyl, of course, it will solve the problem by making 4 traces but it is quite a big trouble manually.